# LibVLCSharp subscribing to "EncounteredError" event

Tags: c#, vlc, libvlc, libvlcsharp

I'm trying to catch errors on RTSP stream and restart several players and recorders.
Current situation:

```
using VLCPlayer = LibVLCSharp.Shared.MediaPlayer;

// Create player 
LibVLC _libVLC = new LibVLC();
VLCPlayer vlcPlayer = new VLCPlayer(_libVLC);
vlcPlayer.EncounteredError += HandleFailedPlayback;
```

```
void HandleFailedPlayback(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, () => {
     SLog.AppendText($"{DateTime.Now} - Fail event detected ... \n");
  });
}
```

however `object sender` seems to be MediaManager and not `VLCPlayer`. How can I access the player for start/stop?

I would expect sender to be VLCPlayer.

Comment: share your full code, VLCPlayer is not a libvlcsharp class

Comment: Sorry forgot to share alias.

Comment: there is no `MediaManager` class in libvlcsharp

Comment: Just store the mediaplayer in your app and access it from various places you need

Comment: But I have at least 6 players. How do I know whitch one emmited  the event?

Comment: just use several handlers redirecting to a method with extra information to identify them. If you think this is a design flaw, feel free to open a ticket